# Intuition behind multiplying matrices of different rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have not touched linear algebra, but my school is teaching matrices. One topic in matrices is on how to do matrix multiplication. However, I was unsatisfied with just remembering the matrix multiplication "algorithm".

Through some online resources, I found out the intuition behind matrix multiplication. Through those resources, I can understand how the "algorithm" is derived, and why for example, matrix multiplication is commutative.

Matrices are the representation of the unit vectors' end values after being put through a linear transformation. A multiplication is applying 2 transformations.

That is when I feel the intuition breaks down.

For this intuition, we are assuming that the matrix is square. A 2D linear transformation is represented by 2×2 matrices, a 3D linear transformation is represented by 3×3 matrices, etc.

For example,
a 2×2 matrix will represent a 2D transformation as
$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}a & c\\ b & d\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ will mean $î = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}a \\ c\end{smallmatrix}\bigr), Ĵ = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}b\\ d\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$.

However, no rules are stating that matrices must be square matrices, or matrices must have the same number of rows and columns for matrix multiplication to occur. Matrices just needs to be compatible (in $AB=C$, $\text{Columns}_A = \text{Rows}_B$).

What is the intuition of multiplying non-square matrices? like  $$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 5 \\ 2 & 7\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) \times \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}6 & 9\\ 2 & 3 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\,?$$

By applying the rules, the result is $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}10 & 15\\ 28 & 42 \\ 26 & 39\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$. Why?

How do we visualize the multiplication of non-square matrices?

I have two ideas

1. Somehow, all matrices can be transformed into a square matrix where that intuition works.
2. There is some sort of non-positive-integer dimension where it will make sense. Maybe a 2.5D where a 3 × 2 matrix works? (That is my wild imagination.) For this possible explanation to work, one must be able to do a transformation of a dimension on another dimension.

I don't have the math vocabulary or competency to figure it out.

Thank you!

Edit:
I found a 3B1B video on this. I am going to use that as my starting point in trying to wrap my head around the weird world of matrices.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8VSDg_WQlA&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=8

Edit2:

This is my proposed answer:
Let there by a $m\times n$ matrix, this represents all the basis vectors in the n dimension mapped to a point in the m dimension. This explains all the general case for matrix multiplication. This also explains compatibility rules.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $k \times m$ matrix. Fact: there exists a matrix $C$ such that $Cx = B(Ax)$ for all vectors $x \in \mathbb R^n$. In other words, multiplying a vector $x$ first by $A$ and then by $B$ is equivalent to just multiplying $x$ by $C$. This matrix $C$ is the product of $B$ and $A$. It’s not immediately obvious what the entries of $C$ are, but you can figure it out and you will discover the standard formula for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative.